# How to insert an order into Infusionsoft via API

Tags: infusionsoft

I have the code to insert the items into to an order as follows,

```
$ordId = 1;
$prodId = 221;
$type = '';
$price = 1000;
$qty = 5;
$desc =  DESC;
$notes = "test notes";
$test = $app->addOrderItem($ordId, $prodId, $type, $price, $qty, $desc, $notes);
```

Is there any functions/methods available for inserting the orders directly into Infusionsoft?

Comment: No there is not, the only thing I can find in API is `OrderService.placeOrder` method which Returns the result of order placement.
Although you can manually add an order against a contact following this [How do I create a manual order?](http://ug.infusionsoft.com/article/AA-00590/0/How-do-I-create-a-manual-order.html)

Comment: me too trying to understand http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/orderservice but no success, please share if you had any success.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the InfusionSoft PHP SDK, you have a couple of options. (1) Use the [OrderService API's `placeOrder()` function](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Order_Service#placeOrder), (2) Use the InvoiceService API to [create a blank invoice](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Invoice_Service#createBlankOrder), [add line items](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Invoice_Service#addOrderItem) to that invoice, and [charge it](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Invoice_Service#chargeInvoice). The OrderService API is a good one-off option; but the InvoiceService allows much more flexibility.

**Using OrderService.placeOrder**

```
$order = $app->placeOrder(
                    (int)$contactId, 
                    (int)$creditCardId, 
                    (int)$payPlanId, 
                    (array(int))$productIds, 
                    (array(int))$subscriptionIds, 
                    (bool)$processSpecials, 
                    (array(str))$promoCodes
               )
```

NOTE: The OrderService API requires you to have already added a Contact via the [ContactService API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Contact_Service#addWithDupCheck), and a Credit Card via the [DataService API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Data_Service#add) (by adding it to the [CreditCard table](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Table_Documentation)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the order service. Details can be found here http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/orderservice

Answer (score -1):

[check the complete code here](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#order-create-an-order)

```
$app = new iSDK();

// perform authorization tasks

$carray = array(
  $app->key,
  $contactId,  
  $creditCardId, 
  $payPlanId, 
  array($productId1, $productId2), 
  array($subscriptionPlanId1, $subscriptionPlanId2), 
  $processSpecials,
  array($promoCode1, $promoCode2)) // array of strings
);

$app->placeOrder($carray);
```